# Complex Riddle. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am small, yet tall.
>
> I am blind, yet have 100 eyes.
>
> I am silky, yet not to the eye.
>
> I crawl, eating humans.

### Who am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> A worm

I am small, yet tall.

> Worms are small but relatively long (tall) for their body weight

I am blind, yet have 100 eyes.

> Worms are blind but are covered in receptor cells in order to sense light.

I am silky, yet not to the eye.

> This refers to the silkworm which produces silk but does not look silky

I crawl, eating humans.

> Worms eat humans when they die.

Comment: Congratulations!